# Editing R1C1 Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am struggling to get the code below right.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("a1") = 10
ws.Range("a2") = 15
ws.Range("c2").Formula = "=A1+A2"
Dim sumadd As Long
sumadd = 5
ws.Range("c2").Formula = ws.Range("c2").Formula + "" + " + sumdadd + """
End Sub
```

I want to replace the formula in c2 with "=A1+A2+5" ie add the value of the sumadd variable to the formula so that it appears in the formula itself. The last line of the code above does not work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title mentions **R1C1** notation, however your code uses "regular" **A1** notation, so I assume that's what you meant...

> ### 'A1' Notation
>
> This is the default method used for creating (and displaying) cell references to other cells. To refer to a cell, enter the column letter followed by the row number, for example `=B2`. The cell reference `=B2` refers to the intersection of column `B` with row `2`. All cell addresses in A1 notation consist of a **column letter and a row number**.
>
> [image: img]
>
> ---
>
> ### 'R1C1' Notation
>
> This notation is also known as **Relative Notation**, not to be confused with [Relative References](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/absolute-relative.htm). This is an alternative way for creating (and displaying) cell references to other cells. `R1C1` cell references are displayed using Row and Column offset values.
>   Displaying your formulas this way often makes the relationships between the cells easier to understand. This shows the same formulas but this time displayed in `R1C1` notation.
>
> [image: img]
>
> ---
>
> The numbers inside the square brackets show how many rows or columns the cell is relative to itself. Negative row numbers mean that the referenced cell is above the cell containing the formula. Negative column numbers mean that the referenced cell is to the left of the cell containing the formula.
>   <sub>([**Source**](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm))</sub>

---

You had a couple issues, including misspelled variable name `sumdadd`, avoidable by using `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [forever], to alert you to undeclared or mis-handled variables and properties.

Also, it's best to use `&` to concatenate text (and `+` for numbers only). You don't need to add any `""` quotes to the formula since it's numeric. **See the links** below for more information.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sumAdd As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        .Range("a1") = 10
        .Range("a2") = 15
        .Range("c2").Formula = "=A1+A2"
        sumadd = 5
        .Range("c2").Formula = .Range("c2").Formula & "+" & sumAdd
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- ExcelJet : [**Dynamic Worksheet Reference**](https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-worksheet-reference)
- MSDN : [**`Option Explicit` Statement** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement)
- MSDN : [**`Range.Formula` Property** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formula-property-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Formula(Formula, NumFormat)` Method (Excel)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa172188.aspx)
- MS [Office Space: **Inserting a Formula Into an Excel Spreadsheet**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692858.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a ton, not only for the answer, but the detailed explanation and the pointers. And also highlighting the missing "Option Explicit" which had also contributed to the confusion.